# DisplayFormat not getting applied to one of two inputs with the same settings

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have two text inputs that appear to be set up exactly the same, however while one gets the decimal places automatically added to it when you click out of the text box, the other one does not. I'm at a loss as to why this could be happening, any help would be much appreciated.

Works:

```
[Display(Name = @"Extra Withholding")]
[UIHint("GridFormFieldDecimal")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? Federal2020ExtraWithholding { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Federal2020ExtraWithholding, 
new { SecondaryLabel = "W-4 Step 4 (c)", 
   OuterCss = "grid_8 alpha", 
   LabelCss = "grid_4", 
   InputCss = "grid_4", 
   HelpCss = "grid_4 display-none", 
   TextCss = "dollars -disable-on-exempt", 
   Prefix = "$" 
})
```

Doesn't work:

```
[Display(Name = @"Other Income")]
[UIHint("GridFormFieldDecimal")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal? OtherIncomeAmount { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OtherIncomeAmount, 
new { SecondaryLabel = "W-4 Step 4 (a)", 
  OuterCss = "grid_8 alpha", 
  LabelCss = "grid_4", 
  InputCss = "grid_4", 
  HelpCss = "grid_4 display-none", 
  TextCss = "dollars -disable-on-exempt", 
  Prefix = "$" 
})
```